# Центрирование окна

Tags: c#, wpf

На кнопку задал изменение размера  окна, т.е. возврат к дефолтным размерам.
Необходимо помимо возврата дефолтных значений окна ещё и разместить окно по центру.
this.Horizontal и VerticalAligment'ы по центру не помогли.

```
private void MaximizeWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (this.Width != 1900 || this.Height != 1000)
                {
                    this.Width = 1900;
                    this.Height = 1000;
                }
                else if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
                {
                    this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                }
            }
```

Comment: По центру чего? А если у юзера 2 монитора?

Comment: По центру первого монитора, ни или как минимум того монитора, на котором изначально было открыто приложение

Comment: То есть вам надо 1) Получить список мониторов 2) Понять кто из них первый 3) вычислить его центр 4) Подвинуть окно в этот центр

Comment: давайте все таки отбросим случай наличия 2-х или более мониторов)

Comment: ну вы можете попробовать что то типа [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4022379/312041)

Comment: Благодарю за потраченное время. Ощущаю себя забаненным в гугле, зря ток ресурс глупым вопросом засорил

Comment: Вы можете перевести тот ответ на русский язык и скопипастить сюда - и уже будет польза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void CenterWindowOnScreen()
{
    double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
    double windowWidth = this.Width;
    double windowHeight = this.Height;
    this.Left = (screenWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
    this.Top = (screenHeight / 2) - (windowHeight / 2);
}
```

Метод, чтобы установить положение окна в центре экрана. Это работает, только если у вас есть 1 монитор, или если все ваши мониторы имеют одинаковый размер. Источник - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4022379